# What equivalent of SizeUp exists for Linux?

Tags: window-manager, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am running an older version of linux (RHEL 5 desktop) and I've been a bit spoiled by the mac desktop I had at my previous job. There are a few niceties I really miss, but the big one is the window management provided by SizeUp.  The feature I'm looking for is a keyboard shortcut to resize and move windows to sides and corners of the screen. Is there such a tool for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using compiz, this can be configured pretty easily. Download the Advanced Compiz settings manager and then look for advanced window resizing.

Comment: Right. RHEL 5 + Compiz -> no go.

Comment: RHEL 5 isn't THAT old, while I have no experience with it I assume some version of compiz would install. I guess it also depends how much access you have to the machine - could you replace the desktop environment with a newer version of gnome?